# Create object at runtime in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight Application in which I want to create dynamic object means i have one silver light class library project IUSERC in that project i have method like

```
public partial class StateMain : CommonERCFunctions
{
  public ObservableCollection<ERC> ErrorCollectionWithValue(string ErrorCode, int MulCopyNo = 0, int VarNo = 0)
   {
    ERC e=new ERC();
    e.name="h";
    retrun e;
   }

}
```

I can create an object like this:

```
IUSERC.State.StateMain sm=IUSERC.State.StateMain();


sm.ErrorCollectionWithValue("dsad",1);
```

Now I want to create that object dynamically.

Can anyone tell me how I can create an object dynamically?

Comment: Your second code snippet will create object at runtime anyway. What you mean dynamically?

Comment: i already refer a link http://supremeware.blogspot.in/2011/03/silverlight-dynamic-user-control-and.html but i didn't get it

Comment: suppose here i know that my dll name is IUSERC but at runtime in XAP file there are lots of dll so bases of parameter passed at runtime using that i have to create a object it may possbile IAYERC,IOKERC so i create dynamic object for that.

Comment: here XXXERC.Sate.StateMain sm=XXXERC.State.stateMain() in XXX will be passed at runtime.

Comment: Try Activator.CreateInstance or Assembly.Load().CreateInstance(), there you can specify typename and get an instance.